# Use of undefined constant mysql_error - assumed 'mysql_error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from the database using but limit it to a certain number of item per view.  But Instead I get the above mentioned error. I created the following function to retrieve the data:

```
//function to display jobs
function display_jobs($start,$per_page)
{
    //Select the data from the database, but limit it to the number of item per page
    $query = "SELECT a.`title`, 
                     a.`vacancyid`, 
                     b.`username`, 
                     c.`date`
                FROM holystic.`vacancy` a
          INNER JOIN holystic.`users` b 
                  ON a.`userid` = b.`userid`
          INNER JOIN holystic.`date` c
                  ON a.`vacancyid` = c.`vacancyid`  
              `LIMIT $start, $per_page;";
    $query_set = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);
    return $query_set;
}
```

When I remove the the `or die(mysql_error)` statement,  I do not get any results. I get results when I type the MySQL Directly on MySQL.  Please assist

Comment: `or die(mysql_error());` and you have an extra backtick at `\`LIMIT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `die(mysql_error());` .. you are missing the paranthesis. It is a function , but you are calling it as a constant.

```
$query_set = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                                                   ^^---- Here
```

Also, remove the backtick before the `LIMT` keyword. [Credits to [`@Prix`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342740/prix) ]

#### Fixed Code..

```
function display_jobs($start,$per_page)
{
    //Select the data from the database, but limit it to the number of item per page
    $query = "SELECT a.`title`, 
                     a.`vacancyid`, 
                     b.`username`, 
                     c.`date`
                FROM holystic.`vacancy` a
          INNER JOIN holystic.`users` b 
                  ON a.`userid` = b.`userid`
          INNER JOIN holystic.`date` c
                  ON a.`vacancyid` = c.`vacancyid`  
               LIMIT $start, $per_page;";
    $query_set = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    return $query_set;
}
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: I modified it according to your advice, Now I get the following error **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`LIMIT 0, 2' **